# How to use RSA to encrypt client_secret for OAuth2 client credential?

Tags: spring-security, oauth, rsa

I build an OAuth server based on this project: https://github.com/Baeldung/spring-security-oauth

This project use BCryptPasswordEncoder to encrypt the client_secret as default. Now I want to use RSA to protect it, and how should I achieve
that?

Any demo or suggestion will be thankful!